# CSS Transition Effects

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS Transition effects. I just added the transition for the background color to be changed as given in the code. But I didn't get the transition effect.

```
.ext-lnk:link
{
    background-color:#1f5ea8;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.ext-lnk:hover
{
    background-color:#b32e37;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Works fine. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9WsPX/). Also you should provide the `HTML` as it most probably a problem with that.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hegecoqo/1/edit?html,output - I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the HTML code i used. But not working. Do i need to add any compatibility tag like thing to HTML page?   <div class="ext-link-contr">
     <a href="#" class="ext-lnk"><img src="images/icon-prtr1.png" /><br /><br />
     <span class="bnr-lft-cont"><strong>Text1</strong></span><br />
     <br /><span class="bnr-lft-cont" style="font-size:12px;">Text2</span></a></div>

Comment: @WebCruzaders Remove `:link`, this seems to cause the problem.

Comment: @Quentin Take a look at this. Im using Chrome 33, when viewing this on JsFiddle it "gliches" as such (Doesnt do the transition and gets stuck on hover) but on JSBin it works fine. Why is this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KG4jZ/) and [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/netazevo/1/) Note: It seems to sometimes work in the JSFiddle one now but always works on the JSBin one... Another update, seems to be a problem with JSFiddle, after running it 2 times it glitchs. Carry on, don't mind me!.